# Filter Twitter DMs to view only unread

Tags: twitter

I would like to filter my Twitter DMs directly in the app/webapp or via 3rd party software to be able to see only unread DMs or responses. I sent a lot of messages myself and it is hard to track responses.

Could you suggest a way to do it or a third-party app that would allow me to filter?